# Log/record of logins to Stack Overflow

Tags: support, login

Is it possible to see a log of my logins (min, successfully, bonus point for unsuccessful attempts) to Stack Overflow?

If so, how do I go about seeing that?

Comment: You can make a [GDPR request](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/request). Then, qa -> SE site (i.e. stackoverflow.com) -> UserHistory.json. The path will make more sense when you Eventually:tm: get your data. This file includes successful login attempts with a date and IP, for all maps with `"type":"login"`. AFAIK, there's no way to show unsuccessful attempts, presumably for data protection purposes.

Comment: Who could have envisioned that GDPR would open-up a whole range of features we previously could only dream of.